# UIViewController and UITabBarController app - viewDidLoad called only once

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, uiviewcontroller

My current application consists of a UITabBarController with 4 different tabs and a UIViewController.  My tabBarController is the rootController and the UIViewController is primarily being used for my user login view.  When the application loads both views are loaded with the login view covering the tabBar.

I have added some logging to my viewDidLoad method for the loginViewController.  I see this method being called on initial launch.  Once the user successfully logs in, the tabBarController view is now viewable.   I setup an action to logout from the tabBarController.  This method sets user/pass to nil and calling a delegate method to load my loginView again.

-(void)setLoginView
{
    [window addSubview:loginController.view];
}

I'm adding some checks but nothing is firing because viewDidLoad (in loginViewController.m)never gets called again.  When logging out my text fields still have the user/pass that was entered when I first logged in.  So one of my checks is to reset the text fields to nil etc..

I may be using the wrong terminology here but is there anyway to "refresh" this loginController where the viewDidLoad method is called every time the user will log out?

Also for the record.  I can't thank everyone enough that has helped answer my previous questions.  It has really helped and I appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`viewDidLoad` will be called only once for each time when the view has been `init`ed. I'm not sure if doing `loginController.view = nil` will cause view to unloaded or not, but I think it should work so next time you access `view` property the view will be loaded again.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe try using `-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {...}` instead of viewDidLoad?

Comment: I added this to my setLoginView method.  -(void)setLoginView
{
 [window addSubview:loginController.view];
 [loginController viewDidLoad]; 
} I now see my log the viewDidLoad method is called.  Acceptable practice?

Comment: hmm. I guess that's probably not "conventional" but if it works it works. :3

Comment: well I don't want to develop any "bad habits" so if there is a more proper method of doing this I'd like to get feedback.

Comment: played around with what you suggested and that's precisely what I needed.  Thanks again.